# Create related object of certain Record Type on Object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, record-type, junction-object

We are using the case object to different case type, due to that we have a lot of different record types. For a case it is possible to have a related Product this is done with a junction object.

So we have a logic like this
Case < Junction object > Product

Previously it people have created a new junction object each time they create a new record type (we have four of these jucntion obejct now), I would like to use a record type instead this would make it more easy to maintain and report on.

However I do not know that best way to create these junction object from the case object. These are the possibilities that I am looking at

- Would it be best to have a custom button for each record type and have the button assign a certain record type
- Would it be best to have a button, a visualforce page and a controller that does the job and redirects to the standard create page with record type set
- or is there a way to have salesforce assign certain record types on
  related object to an object of a certain record type (maybe a flow)?

The fields on the junction object changes depending on which record type the case is.

Hoping for some good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do a trigger as you'd only have to write it once and it should work provided the rt name of case matches the RT name of the junction object.

I threw this together in a few minutes and haven't tested it but it should get you super close:

```
Trigger Sample on JunctionObject (Before Insert, Before Update) {
    Map<String, Id> recordTypeMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (JunctionObject jo : trigger.New)) {
        caseIds.add(jo.Case__c);
    }

    for (Case c : [
        SELECT RecordType.Name
        FROM Case
        WHERE Id IN :caseIds
    ]) {
        recordTypeMap.put(c.RecordType.name, null);
    }

    for (RecordType rt : [
        SELECT Name
        FROM RecordType
        WHERE SObjectType = 'JunctionObject__c'
            AND Name IN :recordTypeMap.keySet()
    ]) {
        recordTypeMap.put(rt.name, rt.Id);
    }

    for (JunctionObject jo : trigger.New) {
        jo.recordTypeId = recordTypeMap.get(jo.Case__c.RecordType.Name);
    }
}
```

This will force all junction objects to copy the record type of their parent case object.

Comment: Hey Toby, thank you. I ended up using buttons. I have a clarification question, it is important to us, that during the create we already have the record type, since the page layout is dependent on it. The trigger here would that not assign the page layout on insert?

Comment: The page layout isn't really "assigned". It's based on record type AND profile and is determined when the record is *viewed* not created; but, for all intent and purposes, you can think of it that way if it makes things easier to understand. Assigning the record type on create should "assign" the page layout. This will happen regardless of the way the record is created. Even if no record type is specified, there will be a default record type used and this record type will result in the default page layout being shown. Again this is a bit of a simplification. Hope that helps.